# Iterating over timeseries data in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am working with historical stock data stored in a dataframe, h2, that looks like so,

```
print (h2)
    
        Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume
    Date                        
    2021-10-14  439.079987  442.660004  438.579987  442.500000  442.500000  70236800
    2021-10-15  444.750000  446.260010  444.089996  445.869995  445.869995  66226800
    2021-10-18  443.970001  447.549988  443.269989  447.190002  447.190002  62213200
    2021-10-19  448.920013  450.709991  448.269989  450.640015  450.640015  46881100
    2021-10-20  451.130005  452.730011  451.010010  451.875000  451.875000  21651910
```

I am trying to iterate over this data with a for loop and I get an error relating to pandas Timestamps,

```
for d,r in h2.iterrows():
     print (d,h2[d])

KeyError: Timestamp('2021-10-14 00:00:00')
```

It seems that iterrows() is changing the type of the index value, so that it becomes in accessible

Is there a better way to iterate over a pandas timeseries

Comment: is it `h[d]` or `h2[d]`? Also, it should be `h2.loc[d]`, which is `r`.

Comment: Yes, it should be h2[d]. Fixed it in the original question. h2.loc[d] makes it work. Thanks

Comment: *Is there a better way to iterate over a pandas timeseries*: avoid for loop if you can, especially on large data.